# Integrating payment gateway in Google Firebase

Tags: firebase, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway into my shopping application. I have a mobile app as well as a web application; both works with firebase.

When I click on the `Pay` button, the user will be redirected to the payment website and on completion, they will redirect to a `return URL` provided by us.

To my knowledge, regardless of the source of the payment trigger; mobile app or web, a firebase function URL should be provided as the `return URL`.

Since this is a publically accessible firebase function URL, how can I verify that the response is a result of a valid transaction?

If this is not the right way, can anyone suggest some recommended practices?

Comment: That's possible with Firebase Functions, but question is too broad

Comment: @DimaRostopira Can you provide any documentation to read more about it so that we can implement it